# call same classes name in diffrent package using loop in java

Tags: java

I have different java package with same class name.let suppose

```
pkg_1.operation;
pkg_2.operation;
pkg_3.operation;
.
.
.
pkg_n.operation;
```

I make a class name test I want to call method Operation from each package.
I want to use loop to avoid hard coding.
Like

```
for(i=0;i< n;i++)
{
    pkg_i.opeartion obj=new pkg_i.operation();
    string output = obj.oper(5); //oper is the method name
}
```

But I cannot find the way to easily do that can you please guide me how I can do that easily.
Otherwise if I have 50 package then I have to write code for 50 packages in instantiation.
Waiting for your advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use reflection -

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("pkg_" + i + ".operation");
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
String output = clazz.getMethod("oper").invoke(obj, 5);
```

But... normally you must not do that and it's a sign of bad design. Instead, use an interface and multiple implementations of it, possibly with a factory.

Also, you are not following the java naming conventions.

Comment: When I do this the following error happen Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: mutants.AOIS_1.ArithOper.oper()
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
 at Test.main(Test.java:31)

Comment: well, then it doesn't. Either it is not public, or it doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("pkg_" + i + ".operation");
    Object object = clazz.newInstance();
    String output = ((Operation) object).oper();
}
```

Assuming, you have a common `Operation` interface for all of your class. Otherwise you need to use Reflection again:

```
clazz.getMethod("oper", Integer.class).invoke(object, 5);
```

Comment: casting won't work, because it is a different Operation class each time

Comment: Then replace by the call with `getMethod` and `invoke`.